# Strategy for delivering static pages in a web application

Tags: architecture, web-development, web-applications, performance

Sometimes in Single Page Applications (SPAs) there are pages like Welcome, About, Help or Support which are just static content and which doesn't require frameworks like Angular. I often see that people just create component for these pages too which is managed by these frameworks.

The other reason is often these pages have different view as compared to when we enter the application.

What is the recommended approach for pages like these? should I put them in web server like Apache's root directory? Do the request for about page needs to be served by the application server?

Comment: Wish down voters would bother to comment. @CodeYogi Please see [what-is-the-problem-with-pros-and-cons](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-is-the-problem-with-pros-and-cons)

Comment: @CandiedOrange updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

Those pages don’t belong in your app. Very likely there’s a person on your marketing or product team who is responsible for the content there. Don’t mix the development team cycle with the marketing cycle. Host those pages on a separate subdomain and even with a separate service that takes care of all the technical details. I would personally use something like Unbounce or Zendesk to host everything and allow the marketing or product non-technical team manage the entire thing.